# When I login I see an attribute error in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, web-crawler

I am going to logging to this URL "https://healthunlocked.com/", then extract posts in this community URL "https://healthunlocked.com/positivewellbeing/posts".

I login but then I have an error in the following command line:

```
all_posts = [post for post in driver.find_element_by_class_name("results-posts").find_elements_by_class_name("results-post") if
                 "results-post" == post.get_attribute("class")]
```

The error is an attribute error :AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_class_name'.

At first, I run the code without logging and it works well, but when I change it to extract posts via a logging account, I see the above error. I insert my whole code below :

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException


driver_path = r"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, options = options)
driver.implicitly_wait(6)

driver.get ("https://healthunlocked.com/")
# click accept cookies
driver.find_element_by_id("ccc-notify-accept").click()
loginpage= driver.find_element_by_id("sitebar-login-button").click()

time.sleep(3)

user_ele = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
user_ele.clear()
user_ele.send_keys('XXXXX')

pass_ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
pass_ele.clear()
pass_ele.send_keys('XXXXX')
# submitting
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/section/div[1]/form/button').click()
time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_link_text('Positive Wellbeing During Self-Isolation').click()
time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_link_text('Posts').click()
time.sleep(3)

post_links = set()
while True:
    #driver.get("https://healthunlocked.com/positivewellbeing/posts")
    all_posts = [post for post in
                 driver.find_element_by_class_name("results-posts").find_elements_by_class_name("results-post") if
                 "results-post" == post.get_attribute("class")]
    # handle clicking more posts
    while len(all_posts) <= len(post_links):

        see_more_posts = [btn for btn in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("btn-secondary")
                          if btn.text == "See more posts"]
        try:
            see_more_posts[0].click()
        except ElementClickInterceptedException:
            # handle floating box covering "see more posts" button
            driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByClassName('floating-box-sign-up')[0].remove();")
            see_more_posts[0].click()
        all_posts = [post for post in driver.find_element_by_class_name("results-posts").find_elements_by_class_name("results-post") if "results-post" == post.get_attribute("class")]
    # popoulate links
    start_from = len(post_links)
    for post in all_posts[start_from:]: # len(post_links): <-- to avoid visiting same links
        # save link
        link = post.find_element_by_tag_name("a").get_attribute("href")
        post_links.add(link)

    # visit the site and scrape info
    for post_site in list(post_links)[start_from:]:

        driver.get(post_site)
        #post_text = driver.find_element_by_class_name("post-body").text
        post_text = driver.find_element_by_class_name("post-body")
        for btn in driver.find_element_by_class_name("post-actions__buttons").find_elements_by_tag_name("button"):
            if "Like" in btn.text:
                post_like = btn.text.split()[1][1]

        #print(f"\n{post_text}\nLikes -->{post_like}\n")
for (post, like) in (zip (post_text, post_like )):
    print (post.text, like.text)
    print('\n')
```

Comment: Did you want the 30 or so posts?

Comment: I want to extract all posts

Comment: Well first I'd handle the infinite loop and then grab all the data.

Comment: Yeah, but before, I need to login.

Comment: Try something like this to open all the  posts prior to grabbing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So on the post I'd loop the see more post and view more. Then grab all the data etc.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://healthunlocked.com/")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#ccc-notify-accept"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#sitebar-login-button"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#email"))).send_keys('a')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#password"))).send_keys('a')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.btn--full-width.btn.btn-primary"))).click()
#Go to the page and so forth.
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,300);")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a.floating-box-sign-up__dismiss.icon-close"))).click()
while True:
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[text()='View more posts']|//button[.='See more posts']"))).click()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break

all_posts=[x.text for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='results-posts']/div[@class='results-post']")]
print(all_posts)
```

Comment: Many thanks. I tried your code but I got the following error :  
  File "C:\Users\thmag\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 128, in __call__
    return _element_if_visible(_find_element(driver, self.locator))

NameError: name '_element_if_visible' is not defined